# How to remove temporary files from CDAP?

Tags: cdap

I am running CDAP server for 24x7. But after 5days of continuous running the server gets restarted, due to the low memory.

CDAP: `sandbox`
OS: `UBUNTU`
CDAP Version: `5.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

Are you running CDAP Sandbox ? CDAP Sandbox is not for running production workloads. It's mainly used for development.